# How do I put together an Avid Outdoor Gazebo / Sun Shade

Tags: self-assembly-furniture

I've lost the instructions to my Avid Outdoor Gazebo / Sun Shade, Model #1083. Avid has gone out of business, and the instructions are not available anywhere on the internet (though there are many questions on several other question-related sites).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are for a 9x13 Canopy #1083.  They may be similar to their many other models.

Inside the package, you will find these poles:

- 4x #1
- 4x #1b
- 3x #2
- 6x #2a
- 4x #3
- 4x #3a
- 4x #4

Connect the #1 & #1b poles together to form 4x4' poles
Connect the #2 & #2a poles together to form 3x6'8" poles (2 - 2a - 2)
Connect the #3 $ #3a & #4 poles together to form 4x6'5" poles

The shorter ones are for the 'Gable'... the canopy.  The #2 poles are the cross-bars for the canopy, and the #3/4 poles are the legs.

Here is what I've found easiest:

1. Assemble the gable completely upside down.
2. Flip it over
3. Add two legs to one of the 9' sides of the gable.
4. Drape the fabric over top
5. Fastening Velcro straps
6. Attach final two legs
7. Attach metal hooks at the bottom of the legs. This is the most difficult part.  Patience is required, or you may bend the poles.
8. Apply stakes to the rings near the bottom of the legs
9. Apply stakes to the extra nylon-rope stabilizers.